# How can I download videos hosted in firebase from my own web page (just by clicking in a "a" tag)?

Tags: html, hyperlink

So I have this web page,
[Click to see image (This is a list of videos... the icon indicated by the arrow is the "a" tag)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLZrp.png) 
 and I want to click in the "a" tag to download the video (which is hosted on firebase)
I tried something like this...

```
 <html>
  <body>
 <a href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/speech-to-text-web.appspot.com/o/dataset%2FAbuse%2Fabusar_x264_0.mp4? 
  alt=media&token=e84607c8-ba77-4c81-99a4-bd42d29cc869" 
  download>click</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

However it just redirect me to the video in a new tab instead of asking where do I want to save the file.

Any suggest about how can I download the video just by clicking in the icon ("a" tag)?

Comment: Maybe right click will do?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) the `download` attribute only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes. Clearly, your firebase URl is not from the same origin as your site, so the attribute has no effect. Other than having some server-side script which acts as a proxy, by fetching the required video from Firebase, then returning the data to the client with headers indicating the browser should try to download it instead of displaying it, I'm not sure there is much you can do. And that probably isn't very efficient either

Comment: I guess I will to create some Node.js service for fetching the video and then sending it to the client. Can you tell how to send the correct headers for telling the browser to download the data instead of display it?

Answer (score -1):

Just move href value to download value.

```
<script>
let el = document.querySelectorAll("a");

el.forEach((v)=>{

let url = v.getAttribute("href");

v.href = "";

v.download = url;

});
    </script>
```

Add this code on page, and click any a tags.

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working. It keeps redirecting me to the link
https://codepen.io/ZetaGH/pen/ZEEKvaY?editors=1111

Comment: Can you download video from external web site or ?

Comment: Yeah I added ");" at the end, but I just getting the HTML raw and I want the **video in mp4 format**